# What is the correct Typescript type for express validation Result?

Tags: express, express-validator

What is the correct type for express validation Result

```
const mapError = (errors: any) =>
  errors.map((error: any) => ({ [error.param]: error.msg }));
```

I have been using any but what should I use now